# Bootstrap datatable not responsive in tabler dashboard for mobile view?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datatable, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

Used bootstrap datable to render data from the database in tabler admin dashboard. it works absolutely fine in desktop view but not in mobile view.

How to fix the issue?

**Desktop view**

[image]

**[image: Mobile View]**

Answer (score 0):

find the datatable css in your bootstrap files

somtimes in main css press ctrl+F Then write datatables

when it cames make `overflow:hidden` TO `overflow-x:auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your datatable inside .table-responsive class

...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the table is responsive by adding the class "`table-responsive`" to the table element. This will enable horizontal scrolling on small screens.